# Stacked column charts

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет!
Есть диаграмма - http://codepen.io/WebCodePro/pen/cdabo

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['API Category', 'Social', 'Music', 'File Sharing', 'Storage',
     'Weather', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2011', 98, 53, 12, 16, 6, ''],
    ['2012', 151, 34, 26, 36, 49, ''],
    ['2013', 69, 27, 22, 17, 15, ''],
  ]);

    var options = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 550,
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3, textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 16 } },
    isStacked: true,

    // Displays tooltip on selection.
    // tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }, 
  };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    // Selects a set point on chart.
    // chart.setSelection([{row:0,column:1}]) 

    // Renders chart as PNG image 
    // chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
  }
```

Тут описание  - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

**Как сделать так, чтобы получилось, как на этой картинке**:

[image]